# CSS Reset and Font-family

Tags: css, inheritance, reset, font-family

```
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, p, div, ul, ol, li {
padding: 0;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
font: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
```

Does someone know why the "font-family" property does not work if I move it  above "font:inherit"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `font` is a shorthand that includes `font-family`.

If you set the same property twice in the same rule-set, then the last one wins.

To illustrate:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px
}
.A {
  border: solid red 1px;
  border-left: dotted blue 2px;
}
.B {
  border-left: dotted blue 2px;
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B"></div>
```